# how to get data sent using Nextjs Api routing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Here is my API file :

```js
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next/types'
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res:NextApiResponse) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        // Process a POST request
    } else {
        // Handle any other HTTP method
        const allAdminUsers = await prisma.admins.findMany()
        console.log("data are: ",allAdminUsers)
        const data = JSON.stringify(allAdminUsers, (_, v) => typeof v === 'bigint' ? v.toString() : v)
        res.status(200).json({ data })
    }
}
```

the line `console.log("data are: ",allAdminUsers)` returns this :

```
[
  {
    id: 1n,
    created_at: 2023-11-29T17:52:40.948Z,
    full_name: 'Ahmed Wagdi',
    username: 'ahmed.w.amin@gmail.com',
    password: 'Yahoo000@',
    is_superuser: true
  }
]
```

but after am trying to call it from another component as follows :

```js
// ** MUI Imports
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper'
import Table from '@mui/material/Table'
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow'
import TableHead from '@mui/material/TableHead'
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody'
import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell'
import TableContainer from '@mui/material/TableContainer'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"




const AdminUsersTable = () => {
  const [admins, setAdmins] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchAdminUsers() {
      try {
        const res = await fetch("/api/admin-users/")
        console.log("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", res)
        setAdmins([]);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
    fetchAdminUsers();
  },[]);

  return (

    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label='simple table'>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            {/* <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell> */}
            <TableCell >Full Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell align='right'>Email(username)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align='right'>Is superuser</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {admins.map((admin: any) => (
            <TableRow
              key={admin.id}
              sx={{
                '&:last-of-type td, &:last-of-type th': {
                  border: 0
                }
              }}
            >
              <TableCell component='th' scope='row'>
                {admin.full_name}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align='right'>{admin.username}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align='right'>{admin.is_superuser}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  )
}




export default AdminUsersTable
```

the line `console.log("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", res)` returns the following :

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/admin-users/', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
```

can't find any thing inside this object holding the data I have sent .. and am enable to access it ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `res.json()` as described here: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/client-side#client-side-data-fetching-with-useeffect